# installing Linux Mint Cinnamon on Dell Inspiron all in one 5420

Tags: linux-mint, boot, windows

guys. I need a straightforward response, just a YES or a NO.

Is it possible to install Linux Mint Cinnamon on Dell Inspiron all in one 5420? Has anyone actually done it, and if yes - HOW???

I have just bought it, convinced I'd be able to run over the pre-installed Windows 11 on it with a nice, reliable LM distro I work with for 6 years now. However, whatever I try, with messing up the bios, with AHCI mode, secure boot disabled, and what not, I simply cannot get the LM to boot from a bootable usb flash drive which I already used to install the OS on an ancient Toshiba laptop from 2009 and a Dell Vostro laptop from 2018. I get the boot menu, choose the 'Start LM' from the available options, and then just a plain black screen, with an underscore in the top left corner of the screen, and the usb flash drive goes dead (the light on it stops blinking).

I am googling this for two days now, but I cannot find anything useful on the topic. So, I guess, this is my last resort.

Please, tell me it's possible. If it isn't, then this is it for me and Dell, we're breaking up for good.

Comment: By knowing the specifications of your laptop https://ubuntu.com/certified/202010-28335/20.04%20LTS the install should be done without problem. LM 20.x should work.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not a Latitude laptop but an All-in-one Inspiron desktop PC. It has a 13th i7 Intel processor, an Intel iRis X 2 gb graphics card, etc. Not really what this Dell Latitude 5420 is made of.
Until I bought it, it never occurred to me I might not be able to boot LM on it, now I  am worried.

Answer (score 0):

Just an epilogue to the story.
Turns out, Ubuntu can be booted; but the very edition I had, Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon (LTS), CANNOT.

I took the PC to a professional, who had to disable secure boot, update BIOS, re-enable secure boot (I think), and what not (I did not watch while he was doing it so I cannot really say), and only then boot the newest Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon Edge (which is meant to be used when other distros or flavour are unsupported by the hardware...).

Understandably, after so much trouble with it, he completely wiped off the pre-installed Windows, and now I can normally boot or reinstall Linux as I wish.

I am shocked and appalled by such work ethics of Dell. This is definitely my last Dell PC. Never again!!!

I will mark this topic as resolved, as the solution was to **use Linux Mint Cinnamon Edge instead of the regular Linux Mint Cinnamon**.